# AS3: How to convert ascii code to character actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to create a board class from canvas, which will 
allow to track click position on it in coordinates like A2, where
A...D is Y coordinate in some scale
and 1...3 is X coordinate

For example
see image http://img.skitch.com/20091001-k6ybfehid6y8irad36tbsiif15.jpg

What I want to create is a kind of convertor from canvas localX and localY to my
new coordinates like A2.

I am thinking of implementing if condition this way

```
if   (0.4 - x*size(from 1-3 here)/canvas.width <= X <= 0.4 + x*size(from 1-3 here)/canvas.width)
       X = x;
```

This way I can assigned needed coordinates in X range. e.g. 1, 2 ,3 etc

But what to do with alphanumeric range. (if for example I want to make it extensible)...

Maybe there is a way to convert ASCII to char? Pls. suggest your solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way as in JavaScript: [fromCharCode](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary691.html). If `y` is an integer starting at `1` for A:

```
String.fromCharCode(64+y)+x
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function fromCharCode in String class to do that.

for example: String.fromCharCode(ascii code);